# How to emulate 'question mark(?)' type generics in Java to C++?

Tags: java, c++, templates

I have a Java code where the return type of a function has unbounded wildcard type (?). How can I emulate something like this in C++? e.g.

```
    public GroupHandlerSetting<?> handleGroupProcessingFor(final EventHandler<T> eventHandler)
    {
        return new GroupHandlerSetting<T>(eventHandler, eventProcessors);
    }
```

Comment: And C++ templates are not even slightly like Java Generics. C++ templates create new types; Java Generics restricts existing types. C++ templates are basically a preprocess with some grafted-on type rules; Java Generics is built on type theory. Don't be seduced by the notation into thinking they are near-equivalents. They aren't.

Comment: Joshua Bloch states in various videos that wildcards should not be used for return types. Are you sure they are a good idea in your case? Can you post the function or at least its signature?

Comment: please, could you add the function?

Comment: @Jon: C++ templates are much more powerful than Java generics. Everything that can be done with generics can be done with templates, while the contrary does not hold.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The question changed rather significantly between my comment and yours by the addition of an enlightening example. :)

Comment: @Jon I am sorry if the example is not much of use. But, I could not a form a complete one. Besides, DavidRodríguez-dribeas answered it before I added the 'enlightening' example :)

Comment: @polapts It's your job to properly specify *your* question. It's not the answerer's job to guess it.

Comment: @EJP: Please, don't: *C++ templates are basically a preprocess with some grafted-on type rules* This is only fueling a misconception. Templates are a complete turing language that can process types and constant expressions. It if *far far away* from a *preprocess* in so many ways... Fueling this misconception does not help anyone.

Comment: Why not just return `GroupHandlerSetting<T>` and ignore the `<?>` thing? Or maybe it should be `GroupHandlerSetting<T extends ?>` or `GroupHandlerSetting<? extends T>`, or something like that? @polapts, can you give us Java code that you are sure is correct, and can you describe clearly how the generics works in that case?  Remember, we might know C++, but we're not all Java Generics experts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ all type arguments must have a name, whether you use it or not, so there is no question mark. Just make it a template argument to the function and give it a name and you should be fine.

```
template <typename T>
struct templ {
   template <typename U>
   void assign( templ<U> & u );      // public void assign<?>( temple<U> u )      
};
```

That's the trivial part, the more complex part is enforcing constraints on the type, and for that you can use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
struct templ {
   template <typename U, typename _ = std::enable_if< 
                              typename std::is_base_of<U,T>::value
                                       >::type >
   void super( templ<U> & u );       // public void super_<? super T>( templ<?> u )

   template <typename U, typename _ = std::enable_if<
                              typename std::is_base_of<T,U>::value 
                                       >::type >
   void extends( templ<U> & u );     // public void extends_<? extends T>( templ<?> u )
}
```

That is using C++11 for the SFINAE, in C++03, it is a bit more convoluted (as if this version was simple) as you cannot use SFINAE on a function template argument, so SFINAE needs to be applied to either the return type or extra function arguments. SFINAE is a much more powerful solution, it can be used not only to provide `super` and `extends` but with many other features of types or compile time values. Google for SFINAE and you will find many cases of SFINAE being used, many of them will be C++03 style.

There was a proposal for concepts that would have greatly simplified the syntax, but no agreement was reached and in a move to push the standard to completion it was deferred for a later standard.

Now, this is really not that common in C++ as it is in Java, so I recommend that you provide a different question with what you want to do, and you will get ideas for designs in more idiomatic C++.

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing. Compare these two at the call site: http://ideone.com/2LXUp and http://ideone.com/bMMJr. If you want to emulate the wildcard, you need type erasure.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Templates and generics are not the same thing, but you can implement all generic code that can be done with generics by using templates. As of your example, C++ does not support that particular *code smell*, note that experts in Java recommend not using `?` in return statements, the reason is that the implementation of the method *knows* the type, so there is no reason not to publish it. The only advantage that `?` provides in a return type is that you don't need to recompile callers if the callee returns a different type for the placeholder...

Comment: ... but that is effectively useless in C++, as templates *must be recompiled*, so binary compatibility (and being able to use a crippled type at the call site --i.e. a type of which you know a couple of little features but which is effectively unknown to you) is not a feature. In your example, in the Java version, you are always returning an `ArrayList<Integer>`, so the equivalent example in C++ would be a plain non-generic function: `std::vector<int> getSomeList()`. In the question, the method is part of a generic class (guessing from `T`), thus a non-templated member function of a template.

Comment: ... With that change the call site becomes much more similar in both languages: `int x = getSomeList().size();` ouch, *exactly* the same!

Comment: Yes, my example is trivial on purpose. But note that there are indeed uses of ? return types, even if rare. The Java standard library has an example in [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That is a strange case, whose only purpose is avoid having to write huge amounts of covariant return types because the language does not allow you to provide a generic implementation. In C++ you would have `ClassBase& getClass()` in `Object`, and then every type `T` extending `Object` would return `Class<T>& getClass()` where `Class<T>` would be a template that extends `ClassBase` and provides the specific type-safe member functions. As I mentioned before, when `?` is used for the return type, you get a crippled type on which only *generic* operations can be called...

Comment: ... and at any rate if the *sensible* examples come exactly from where the two languages differ the most (type system, all non-primitive types have a common base), I am not so sure that it applies to C++. That is, the `Class<?>` can be used at all because the language provides a very rich interface for the generic version based on the fact that *everything is an `Object`*, which cannot be automatically done in C++ (and in manually implementing it, the approach above fits the requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Your specific example is easily done, and since I don't use Java, I can't understand why it needs the `<?>` there. In C++, you just fill in the same template parameter:

```
template<class T>
GroupHandlerSetting<T> handleGroupProcessingFor(EventHandler<T> const& evHandler){
  return GroupHandlerSetting<T>(evHandler, evProcessors);
}
```

`T` will get deduced from whatever argument is passed to `handleGroupProcessingFor`, and we use just the same `T` for the return type, basically exactly what you do in the body of the function.

Comment: I am not sure about this. If I could simply replace <?> with <T> then I think it's possible to do in Java also. Not sure why <?> is needed. I have little knowledge of Java so I might be  wrong.

Comment: @polapts: Reading the comment on David's answer, it seems `<?>` is needed for type erasure. In your specific example, you can get away with simple argument deduction.

Comment: @Xeo: `?` is a type placeholder, basically another type argument that you don't even care to name. You can place some constraints on what the *unknown* type is, namely you can require it to be a base or to derive from another type (whether generic argument or fixed type). The difference between your code and the question code is that in your code the type `T` is bound to be the same in both the argument and the return statement, while in the question's code it isn't (internally you could return `GroupHandlerSetting<foo>` regardless of `T` and it would compile. It is bad design though.